# Antisymmetrize a rank 4 tensor

Tags: tensors

Suppose I have a rank 4 tensor $T_{abcd}$, I can build a SparseArray to input some initial values like $T_{1435}=1$ (a huge amounts of elements are equal to 1) etc. Now I want to antisymmetrize this tensor, then automatically diagonal terms are all 0, and $T_{4135}=T_{1453}=T_{1345}=T_{3415}=T_{5431}=T_{1534}=-1$ and $T_{4153}=1$ etc. How can I achieve this?

PS: I have tried SymmetrizedArray, but it can not do something like {{1,2,3,4},{2,1,4,2}} -> 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to add `Antisymmetric[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`:

```
sa = SymmetrizedArray[
  {{1, 4, 3, 5} -> 1},
  {5, 5, 5, 5}, 
  Antisymmetric[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
]
```

Then you can simply visually check with

```
Normal[sa] // MatrixForm
```

that by specifying just $T_{1435} = 1$ above, you automatically get $T_{4135}=T_{1453}=T_{1345}=T_{3415}=T_{5431}=T_{1534}=-1$ and $T_{4153}=1$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One problem I am having with this method is that I have created a huge amount of list contains the position of 1s. But SymmetrizedArray does not allow operation like list->1, and I am not sure how to assign each element in the list to 1 in this case (because there are too many).

Comment: @lol Suppose your list is `list = {{1,2,3,4},{2,1,4,2}}`. Use the following as the first argument of `SymmetrizedArray`: `# -> 1 & /@ list`.